# Removing corresponding rows/columns in matrix using python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matrix

I am working with a 1400x1400 correlation matrix using pandas/numpy and my goal is to remove both the rows and columns that use a given variable name. Each row and column has the name of the variable and the correlation between those two variables:

```
            abandon abhorrent abominable
abandon     1.00    0.12      0.10
abhorrent   0.12    1.00      0.99
abominable  0.10    0.99      1.00
```

To convert the dataframe to a matrix I use as_matrix:

```
datafile = pd.read_csv('data.csv')
df_matrix = datafile.as_matrix
```

I am having trouble understanding how to create a new dataframe without including, for instance, the variable "abandon" (i.e., removing both the column and the row that corresponds to "abandon").

To begin, I've tried tried to just select a single column to get an understanding of how I might create a list of variables that I want:

```
df_matrix = datafile.as_matrix(columns=['abhorrent'])
```

However this returns just the arrays and I lose all of the row/column names.

I also tried to delete the rows/columns after importing the data. This would require that I take the extra step of forming a list of the variable names that I don't want and then pass them on as column/row numbers, but that seems doable. I'm not sure this code is completely correct however:

```
df_matrix2 = np.delete(df_matrix, 1, axis=0)
df_matrix2 = np.delete(df_matrix, 1, axis=1)
```

This code, as far as I can tell, isn't producing any changes in the new matrix. It is still a 1400x1400 matrix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use [DataFrame.drop()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html) method:

```
In [9]: df
Out[9]:
            abandon  abhorrent  abominable
abandon        1.00       0.12        0.10
abhorrent      0.12       1.00        0.99
abominable     0.10       0.99        1.00

In [10]: df.drop('abandon', 1).drop('abandon')
Out[10]:
            abhorrent  abominable
abhorrent        1.00        0.99
abominable       0.99        1.00
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's one with row-col indexing -

```
In [32]: df
Out[32]: 
            abandon  abhorrent  abominable
abandon        1.00       0.12        0.10
abhorrent      0.12       1.00        0.99
abominable     0.10       0.99        1.00

In [33]: strg = 'abandon'

In [34]: df.iloc[df.index!=strg, df.columns!=strg]
Out[34]: 
            abhorrent  abominable
abhorrent        1.00        0.99
abominable       0.99        1.00
```